# hts package: generating node structure

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, forecasting

I'm trying to create the node structure for a hts—can anyone help me get this right?

The hierarchy I am working with has 4 levels (excluding total).

```
Category => Sub_category => Product_type => Product
```

I can simplify it to the following for reproducibility:

```
structure <- data.frame(H1 = rep(1:2, rep(12, 2)),
                        H2 = rep(1:4, rep(6, 4)),
                        H3 = rep(1:8, rep(3, 8)),
                        H4 = 1:24)
```

Given the above structure, how can I construct the node argument for `hts()`?  I've read the documentation but still can't quite get my head around it for structures with more than 2 levels.  There's an [old question along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579292/how-to-use-hts-with-multi-level-hierarchies), for which the answer is now out of date (I think).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `structure` data frame, it uses the following node structure:

```
nodes <- list(2, rep(2, 2), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 8))
```

Each element of the list gives the number of children for each node at that level.

It becomes clearer if a tree plot can be drawn before making a list of `nodes`:

```
=> A
  => AA
    => AAA
      => 3 bottom time series
    => AAB
      => 3 bottom time series
  => AB
    => ABA
      => 3 bottom time series
    => ABB
      => 3 bottom time series
=> B
  => BA
    => BAA
      => 3 bottom time series
    => BAB
      => 3 bottom time series
  => BB
    => BBA
      => 3 bottom time series
    => BBB
      => 3 bottom time series
```

I hope that helps in constructing a node structure with more than 2 levels.

Comment: Thanks for your help here guys.  I have it working now.  I have many thousands of child time-series so it was becoming quite confusing.