# How to use ‘hts’ with different numbers of timeseries on multi-level hierarchies?

Tags: r, forecasting

I am facing multi-level hierarchies while forecasting several time series.

This is a sample of my structure:

```
Total

  => A

    => 19 time series

  => B

    => 10 time series
```

So I need to handover 31 time series to the hts function.

I tried

```
nodes <- list(2, rep(1, 19), rep(1, 10))
```

but only got this:

```
Error: The number of terminal nodes is not consistent with the number of bottom time series.
```

I checked out this ([How to use ‘hts’ with multi-level hierarchies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579292/how-to-use-hts-with-multi-level-hierarchies)), but also does not help me.

It would be so fantastic if anybody can help me find the nodes to hand over the correct hierarchical structure to the hts function.

**Edit:**
I was able to find the solution by myself:

```
nodes <- list(2,c(19,10))
```

And in addition to that I had to use a time series frame only containing the 29 (19+10) time series. Not the aggregated ones ( A / B).

Comment: Welcome! It's hard for us to tell what you are asking from the "it does not work" statement. Could you edit your question to show what your current output is vs. what the expected output should be? See [how to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for this advise, I added the error message.